# In the figure given below, assume that the diode and op-amp are ideal. \$V_{i}\$ varies from +1V to -1V. How will the output voltage \$V_{0}\$ vary?

Tags: operational-amplifier

\$V_{0}=-(\frac{R_{eqivalent}}{1*10^3})V_{i}\$

\$R_{equivalent}=\frac{4*4}{4+4}*10^3=2*10^3\$

\$V_{0}=-(\frac{2*10^3}{1*10^3})V_{i}\$

\$V_{0}=-(2)V_{i}\$

For \$V_{i}\$ varying from +1V to -1V, the output voltage \$V_{0}\$ will vary from -2V to +2V.

[image]

Comment: Is the solution correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct. You seem to have neglected the ideal diode.

If the output is > 0 (meaning the input is < 0) then the diode will not conduct, so the gain will be higher than your calculation.

If the output is <0 (meaning the input is > 0) then the diode will conduct, so the gain will be as you say.

Comment: +1 for saying "higher than your calculation" instead of giving the answer!